# How to get Illustrator export into shortcut?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, export, cc-2014, shortcuts

I am an avid InDesign user and a big fan of shortcuts.  In InDesign you can use the shortcut <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to export items within InDesign but this feature is not a default in Illustrator.  How can I add the export shortcut to Illustrator?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this in Illustrator by navigating to `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts`:

[image]

You will get the Keyboard Shortcuts panel:

[image]

The default view is for Tools so you will need to click the drop down and select `Menu Commands`:

[image]

Once in menu commands you click the carat for `File` and navigate to Export:

[image]

Click within the Shortcut till it highlights orange and then click <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and it will show up:

[image]

You will be prompted that <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is over-riding the GPU preview command but I never use it so that is up to you.  Once you click `OK` you will be requested to give the keyset file a name, I called mine `export_shortcut`:

[image]

Press `OK` and have fun with your enhanced workflow.